# 3 Column structure where the 2 outer columns are being dragged to the bottom of screen

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a 3 col set up and when the page loads the two outer columns get pushed to the bottom of the screen. I can't move them using margins and believe it may be related to the center column which imports an external feed. I've spent hours on this with no resolution in sight. Any help would be extremely grateful for. webpage http://carrickswan.com/fix-test/

Sorry about the inline css it makes it look messy but hopefully someone can see the issue from the live page.

```
     <!-- col 1 -->
    <div style="background-color: white; width: 18%; margin: 25px 20px 0px           40px; display:inline-block;">
    <div>
        <h2 style="width: inherit; color: white; background-color: #2e2d2d; padding: 5px; background-image: url('http://carrickswan.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/header-bg2.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;" class="col-title">PLAY ONLINE</h2>
        <a href=""><img src="http://carrickswan.com/wp-   content/uploads/2016/04/pay.jpg" alt="play swan lotto"></a>
    </div>

      <div>
        <h2>MEMBERSHIP</h2>
        <a href=""><img src="http://carrickswan.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/membership.jpg" alt="pay swan membership"></a>
     </div>
    </div>

   <!-- col 2 -->
   <div id="content" style="background-color: white; width: 50%;   display:inline-block; margin: 25px;">
    <div id="content_fixtures"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- col 3 -->
    <div style="width: 18%; display: inline-block; margin-top: 0px; background-color: white;">
    <h2 class="title" style="color:white; background-color: #2e2d2d;  padding: 5px; background-image: url('http://carrickswan.com/wp- content/uploads/2016/04/header-bg2.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;">LOTTO</h2>
    <?php $cat_id = 7; //the certain category ID
    $latest_cat_post = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 1, 'category__in' => array($cat_id)));
    if( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : while( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : $latest_cat_post->the_post();  ?>

    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>   
    <div style="padding:5px;">
        <?php the_content($more_link_text,$strip_teaser); ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="more-link">Read More</a>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to the two outer divs - I tried it on your page and it worked.

Comment: Thanks works a treat. Simple solution really I haven't being writing enough code of late! Still can't understand what was driving them down though.

Comment: I saw that there is some general setting `vertical-align: baseline` which caused that. However, I don't remember which selector it had - propably from some reset CSS that's in there.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to make them align top

here is the solution

wrap your 3 divs within container

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="column one">
  <div class="column two">
  <div class="column three">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main-container
{
display:flex;
}
.main-container .column
{
flex:1;
}
```